# Can I use this relay for DC

Tags: ac, dc, solid-state-relay

[image]

http://www.dx.com/fr/p/ssr-25da-25a-solid-state-relay-white-134494#.VDmPWPl_uap

It says AC output but how can this transform DC to AC ? Shouldn't this act like a switch ? If my circuit is DC and I close the switch it will transform to AC or will it stay DC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to one review on DX:

> by Docteh on 11/26/2012 Involvement:Expert (understands the inner workings) - Ownership:1 week to 1 month
>
> Pros:
>   Works perfectly. There is a red LED on the DC side of the Solid State Relay. This one also comes with a plastic cover. The cover has holes that allow a screwdriver to go in and be used without the cover.
>
> Cons:
>   Appears to use more power on the DC side than a similar more pricier SSR like the Crydom ones. **Another downside is that AC SSRs such as this only turn off at the zero crossing point, which means you have to use this with AC voltage on the output side.**

Most likely (as no datasheet or part list to confirm), it uses a Triac or similar for the actual load control switching, which means that no current can be flowing for it to turn off. On AC, this is simple as the AC signal crosses the Zero point between Positive and Negative. On DC, the DC signal needs to be off for that to happen. It's a catch 22.

**So no, you need a DC switching SSR. This one will not work well for you.**

Comment: Answer outside quotation box + bold text is useful. Most of the quoted material from Docteh is irrelevant to this users understanding and more liable to mislead than help. The part in bold is good and relevant. (I know you know that :-).) I'd suggest leaving the attribution and the bold part and deleting the rest. I could have edited it and done that myself but I'd expect that to annoy people so I submit it as a suggestion for your valued consideration :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the reason I left it as the review is to provide context. As there is no datasheet or any other authoritative source of information, that single review is the only reliable (if subjective) source available.

Answer (score 2):

KG-25DA

Voltage Range (V)
Input:3-32VDC,
Output:24-380VAC,
Rated Current (mA) 25000,
Material Plastic,
Dimensions (cm) 6.2*4.5*2.5,
Weight (kg) 0.098,…

[From here](http://www.couponproduct365.net/discount-kongin-kg-25da-24-380vac-solid-state-relay-are-now-available)

---

You are asking two different questions (ie "Can I use this relay for DC?" and "can it transform DC to AC?").

**The answer to both is "No!".**

**Answers here. Reasons below:**

> Can I use this relay for DC

DC output - **no**.

> It says AC output but how can this transform DC to AC ?

It cannot and does not and that is not it's job.

> Shouldn't this act like a switch ?

Yes. It is a controlled switch. See below for details.

> If my circuit is DC and I close the switch it will transform to AC or will it stay DC ?

Neither. It does not transform anything. The **control** input accepts DC. The **switched** output switches only AC. they are not connected, transformed or changed.

---

**Explanations:**

This is an electronic device designed to act as an electrically controlled switch.
A low powered control or input signal is used to control (turn on and off) a high powered output or "LOAD".

**The load** is intended to be a high voltage high current **AC** powered device.
Low voltage and current AC powered devices can be controlled down to certain minimum levels.
While it will work in some very special cases with a DC load these are not normal or useful.

**The control signal** is intended to be a low voltage low current **DC** signal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand quite how an SSR works.

Basically you provide a DC signal which "activates" the relay.  At that point a virtual switch inside the unit connects the two AC terminals together. It is designed to switch AC power on and off.

You can think of it as a high powered opto-isolator - you provide the "LED" signal and the AC connections are equivalent to the switched transistor collector and emitter.

Comment: Yes but what happens if I connect two DC together, will it transform it to AC ?

Comment: @user2591935: It does not transform anything. It is a switch.

Comment: So If I use this for DC it will work ?

Comment: To switch a DC power signal?  Possibly, but not guaranteed. There is a possibility it will turn it on but never turn it off - depending on the design.

Comment: @user2591935  Assume that that particular solid state relay can not switch a DC voltage, look for another relay that's rated for DC.

Comment: Ok. But it's weird I don't understand why AC/DC matters it's just a switch.

Comment: It [solid state relay] is not "just" a switch, it's an electronic semiconductor device.  It's like saying a microcontroller's just "a lump of black plastic".